# Basic Java Turtle Graphics Animation

Tags: java, oop

I am writing a program that is near finished but I am stuck on a few minor issues. I am writing a program to move animated turtles around the display output. My program runs perfectly, however I need to have a tester class, which will call my functions in an OOP style, which I am not sure how to implement. Also, the program code must allow the user to affect the animation, another point I need help with.

If someone would be able to type up some code that would help with these problem(s), it would be VERY much appreciated. Thank you.

This is an animated program that will move animated, colored turtles around the screen.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args){
new Runner().run();
  }//end main method
}//end class Main
//------------------------------------------------------//

class Runner{

  Random randGen = new Random(new Date().getTime());


  int aquariumWidth = 450;
  int aquariumHeight = 338;
  World aquarium = new World(
                        aquariumWidth,aquariumHeight);


  List turtleList = aquarium.getTurtleList();
  //----------------------------------------------------//

void run(){
aquarium.setPicture(new Picture("aquarium.gif"));

int numberTurtles = 8;


for(int cnt=0;cnt < numberTurtles;cnt++){
  int xCoor =
          Math.abs(randGen.nextInt() % aquariumWidth);
  int yCoor =
         Math.abs(randGen.nextInt() % aquariumHeight);
  new Turtle(xCoor,yCoor,aquarium);
}//end for loop

int angle = 0;
int leaderMove = 0;

Turtle turtle = null; //empty container
Turtle testTurtle = null; //empty container 


Turtle leader = (Turtle)turtleList.get(0);
leader.setShellColor(Color.RED);
int turtleLength = leader.getHeight();


turtle = (Turtle)turtleList.get(3);
turtle.setBodyColor(Color.YELLOW);
turtle.setShellColor(Color.ORANGE);
turtle = (Turtle)turtleList.get(7);
turtle.setBodyColor(Color.ORANGE);
turtle.setShellColor(Color.YELLOW);

while(true){//animation loop will run forever

  leaderMove = (int)(turtleLength/2
               + turtleLength*randGen.nextDouble()/4);

  angle = (int)(45*(randGen.nextDouble() - 0.5));


  for(int cnt = 0;cnt < turtleList.size();cnt++){
    turtle = (Turtle)turtleList.get(cnt);
    turtle.penUp();//no turtle tracks allowed

    //Force the turtles to maintain some distance
    // between them 
    for(int cntr = 1;cntr < turtleList.size();cntr++){
      testTurtle = (Turtle)turtleList.get(cntr);
      //Use size as a part of the equation and increasy by one
      if((testTurtle != turtle) && (cnt != 0)){
        int separation = (int)(turtle.getDistance(
          testTurtle.getXPos(),testTurtle.getYPos()));

          if(separation < 2*turtleLength){

            turtle.turnToFace(testTurtle);
            turtle.turn(180);
            turtle.forward(turtleLength/3);
          }//end if
      }//end if
    }//end for loop on turtle separation

    if(cnt == 0){
      //This is the leader

      int xPos = leader.getXPos();
      int yPos = leader.getYPos();

      if(xPos < turtleLength){
        leader.setHeading(90);
      }else if(xPos > aquariumWidth -turtleLength -2){
        leader.setHeading(-90);
      }//end else

      if(yPos < turtleLength){
        leader.setHeading(180);
      }else if(
             yPos > aquariumHeight -turtleLength - 2){
        leader.setHeading(0);
      }//end else


      leader.turn(angle);
      leader.forward(leaderMove);
    }else{

      turtle.turnToFace(leader);
      int distanceToLeader = (int)(turtle.getDistance(
                  leader.getXPos(),leader.getYPos()));
      turtle.forward(distanceToLeader/10);
    }//end else

  }//end for loop processing all turtles

 //This took some looking over to find the right methods to control the speed. 
  try{
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);
  }catch(InterruptedException ex){
  }
}

}
}
```